# Paging on a future post loop?

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, pagination, loop

I am trying to get paging to work on my future post loop, but to no avail. I am getting no links, when I expect them at the bottom, for pagination despite there being several valid posts in the database.

```
<?php
$args = array( 
    'post_type' => 'program',
    'paged' => get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1,
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'post_status' => "future",
    'order_by' => 'date',
    'order' => 'ASC'
);
$program = new WP_Query;
$program->query( $args );



if($program->have_posts()): while($program->have_posts()): $program->the_post(); ?>

//The content loop
<?php endwhile; ?> 
    <div><?php previous_posts_link('&laquo; Previous'); ?></div>
    <div><?php next_posts_link('More &raquo;'); ?></div>
<?php endif; ?> 
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

---

**Update** *Further Info*

I have established that $program->max_num_pages always displays the correct number of pages, so using the `offset` argument for `WP_Query`, I have been able to roll my own paging. But this seems like it's asking for trouble!!

---

**Update** *Further Info*

I have taken the rather drastic step of extending the WP_Query object. This is really over the top, but I have to make this work:

```
class MF_Query extends WP_Query{
    function __construct(array $args){
        if(!array_key_exists('posts_per_page',$args)) $args['posts_per_page'] = 10;

        $args['offset'] = (isset($_GET['page'])?($_GET['page']-1)*$args['posts_per_page']:0);
        parent::query($args);
    }

    function mf_next_page($link_text = "Next"){

            $curPage = intval((isset($_GET['page'])?$_GET['page']:1));//Use 1 if $_GET['page'] not set

            $link = "<a href='".remove_post_vars(curPageURL());

            if($curPage<$this->max_num_pages){
                return $link.constructQuery($this->merge(array("page"=>$curPage+1),$_GET))."'>".$link_text."</a>";
            } else {
                return false;
            }


    }
    function mf_prev_page($link_text = "Prev"){

            $curPage = (isset($_GET['page'])?$_GET['page']:1);//Use 1 if $_GET['page'] not set
            $link = "<a href='".remove_post_vars(curPageURL());
            if($curPage>1){
                return $link.$this->constructQuery($this->merge(array("page"=>$curPage-1),$_GET))."'>$link_text</a>";
            } else {
                return false;
            }


    }
    private function constructQuery(array $query){


        $url_ext = "?";
        foreach($query as $k => $v){
            $url_ext .=$k."=".$v."&amp;";
        }
        $url_ext = substr($url_ext, 0, -5);//chop last ampersand off


        return $url_ext;

    }
    private function merge($get, $put){
        //Get values from one array, and put them in another (overriding existing values if appropriate)
        foreach ($get as $k => $v){
                $put[$k]=$v;
        } 
        return $put;

    }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adjacent post fetching relies on quite a bit of custom SQL inside. One of the assumptions it makes in that SQL is that you are only looking for published post.

You can [use filter in `get_adjacent_post()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_adjacent_post#Filters) (that is used internally by those next/previous functions) to alter the query and get rid of published only limitation.

Comment: In your opinion, is there anything innately wrong with my current approach? Because it is working, so would save having to start working another solution out!

Comment: @Mild Fuzz lol, I don't even get what your current approach does, so no opinion on that :)

Comment: ha, it adds new "next" and "previous" page link methods creating pages via a get variable. I  use this with the using the `$max_num_pages` property of the WP_Query object to determine loop offset on each page.